# Use SAS overlay with different colors for a given year

Tags: sas

I have the following piece of code which plots population figures `yr1946` `yr1953` etc with another numeric variable titled `Land_Area`

The following creates a plot for each year with a distinct color, How do I include a legend that says which color is associated with which year. This is what I have so far.

```
symbol1 value=dot color=red; 
symbol2 value=dot color=green;
symbol3 value=dot color=yellow;
symbol4 value=dot color=green;


proc gplot data=Slpopwip;
plot yr1946*Land_Area=' ' yr1953*Land_Area=' ' yr1963*Land_Area=' ' yr1971*Land_Area=' ' /OVERLAY;
title'Overlay';
run;
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: If you can, you should switch to SGPLOT, you get better colours and options to control your graphs and they're better quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the term `LEGEND` to the plot statement.  Below is an example.

```
symbol1 value=dot color=red; 
symbol2 value=dot color=green;
symbol3 value=dot color=yellow;
symbol4 value=dot color=green;

data slpopwip;
  call streaminit(7);
  do _n_ = 1 to 10;
    land_area = floor(rand('uniform')*1000);
    yr1946 = floor(rand('uniform')*1000);
    yr1953 = floor(yr1946 + rand('Uniform')*200);
    yr1963 = floor(yr1953 + rand('Uniform')*200);
    yr1971 = floor(yr1963 + rand('Uniform')*200);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc gplot data=Slpopwip;
plot yr1946*Land_Area=' ' yr1953*Land_Area=' ' yr1963*Land_Area=' ' yr1971*Land_Area=' '
  /OVERLAY LEGEND;
title'Overlay';
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Note: consider using ODS Graphics (SGPLOT etc.) instead of SAS/GRAPH, as ODS Graphics are nicer and easier to use.